# How LC oscillators work with a continous DC power supply

Tags: oscillator

I am having serious trouble understanding oscillators. I read a lot of articles and books 
but no one explained it simply and intuitively.

From what I know, LC circuits oscillate for a small amount of time if the battery is disconnected from them, so how could they oscillate with a continuous power supply as I find it in oscillators like Hartley oscillator, where the battery is connected directly to the LC part ,

I find it very unintuitive and hard to understand. I wish it could be explained, using a flow of water analogy or something like that, how could a continuous DC at the input become a continuous AC at the output.

Comment: Did you understand the working of it?

Answer (score 5):

Oscillators that run continuously require something somewhere to have gain at least a bit over 1 at the oscillating frequency.  A L-C tank does not oscillate continuously on its own.  It can if connected to the right amplifier in the right way.

Think of any amplifier with a gain over 1 where the output is AC coupled back to the input.  There will always be some noise, so the output moves slightly, let's say it goes up for sake of example.  That drives the input up, which makes the output go more up, which makes the input go more up, etc.

Eventually the amplifier output hits a limit and can't go up anymore.  Now the input is no longer changing.  Remember that the input is AC coupled to the output.  A flat level on the output results in a 0 level on the input eventually.  With the output clipped no longer changing, the input decays towards 0.  At some point, the input isn't high enough to keep the output at maximum, so the output begins to fall.  That falling output makes the input even lower, and the whole process repeats, this time with the output at its minimum level.

That's the basics of how oscillators work.  The details are in getting them to produce a nice wave shape and predictable frequency.

Comment: Adding concept of phase shift from output to input would be useful.

Comment: Two comments: (1) It is the LOOP GAIN (not the gain of the amplifier) that is required to be slightly larger than unity (this applies also to workable oscillators with a parallel tank circuit). (2) It is not the noise that starts oscillations. Instead, it is the switch-on transient after external power is applied.

Answer (score 2):

@OlinLathrop already gave you an excellent explanation in technical terms. Since you requested also some simple analogy, I'll try to provide one.

Think of an LC tank circuit as a [swing](https://www.flickr.com/photos/looking_and_learning/8338878367).

If you give the swing a push it will oscillate for a while until it comes to rest again. But if you give a push to the swing each time it comes down, then the oscillation can go on forever (well, at least until you become too tired). The transistor in the circuit acts like the person pushing the swing. It takes its muscle energy (the DC supply power) and converts it into pushes to the swing.

If you have any experience with swings you know that to obtain a good, permanent oscillation, you cannot push the swing randomly, but you have to push at the right moment and in the right direction (*with the right phase*). In the LC oscillator the transistor can do that: it "sees" when it is the right moment to push and then "pushes". And you should remember that the oscillation period of the swing wasn't something that you could set arbitrarily, but it depended on the physical characteristics of the swing, such as the length of the ropes and the weight of the person sitting on it (in electrical terms these are the values of C and L).

Of course there is a bit of oversimplification in my analogy, but it should give a more intuitive way to see the operation of the circuit as explained by @Olin.

Just to mention one bit of oversimplification: in the LC oscillator the transistor doesn't "push" once in a while, as the swing analogy could lead you to think, but "pushes continuously" since the circuit behaves linearly (at least so do most common LC oscillators).

Comment: i have to say both of you didn't answer my question , if u grabbed a swing and push with your hand without letting go , it wont swing , unless if you let go , but the dc battery is connected directly to the LC witch means current is flowing  continuously , so how did it swings

Comment: @themigrant LC tank circuits are used in many different topologies. It is difficult to answer without seeing to which circuit you are referring to. Please, post a specific schematic. And the analogy, as I said, is oversimplistic. The "push to the swing" is the act of providing energy to the tank LC. How this is accomplished depend on the specific circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short description of the PRINCIPLE:

Think of an oscillator as an AMPLIFIER that is able to produce its own input signal - for one frequency only. For this purpose you need an amplifier with positive feedback for this single frequency. Let´s assume that you have a passive bandpass (an LC tank is such a bandpass) with a maximum output-to-input damping ratio of 1/3 (this is, for example, the case for the WIEN RC bandpass). In this case, you are using an amplifier with a gain of three that is connected to the passive bandpass in series. Then, connect the amplifier output to the bandpass input (both form a closed loop) - and you have a working oscillator. For all frequencies above and below the mid-frequency the gain is not able to compensate the damping of the passive circuit and all oscillations will die out.

**UPDATE:**
In case your question concerns the simple (but uncommon) case of connecting a battery directly to a passive LC tank circuit: Yes - if you give only a short pulse on the tank circuit (high Q, less damping) it will show decaying oscillations. And if you let the circuit connected to the battery there will be no oscillations at all because the internal resistance of a voltage source (battery) is very small. That means: Your LC tank is heavily damped and is not able to show any oscillations. Does THIS answer your question?

Comment: is it so hard to understand my question , i mean how did the oscillation started if the oscillator is not disconnected from the battery

Comment: OK - it seems you are NOT asking for a description of a working oscillator. Instead you want to know what a LC tank circuit does if it is connected to a battery (not an amplifier), OK? Strange question! However, I have updated my detailed answer.

Comment: i think u are close to the answer , please bear with me , i will die if i didn't understand how the oscillator starts oscillating , there is something wrong in your answer u said there is damped oscillation despite the fact it wasn't disconnected from the battery , from what i read , damped oscillations starts only if u disconnect the battery .

Comment: No - you misunderstood something. Damped/decaying  oscillations occur only if you give a short time energy pulse into the tank circuit. In this case, the energy swings between both reactive elements (L and C) back and forth because these elements can store the energy. However, due to ohmic losses during this process, some energy is continuously lost and oscillation amplitudes decrease.

Comment: ok , but what am saying in the beginning when u close the switch , the capacitor get charged and the battery is still connected , so how did the oscillation started in these feed back oscillators , where did the ac input came from , there is no pulse from the battery , its continuous DC

Comment: No - in this case (battery remains connected) there are no oscillations at all. And - it is not a "feedback oscillator". There is no feedback at all. It is just a circuit which "sucks" current out of the battery.